# Looping on rows of a table with a cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update a table with demo data, so I decided to build a little `stored procedure`.

Here it is:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Tommy Bergeron
-- Create date: 2011-07-10
-- Description: This SP updates a Patient's CreateDate row
-- with realistic demo DateTime data.
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdatePatientCreateDateWithDemoData @PatientID int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @IncrementalDateTime DATETIME,
    @BGID int,
    @CreateDate DATETIME

    -- Setting starting datetime    
    SET @IncrementalDateTime = '2012-01-01 10:00 AM'

    -- Declaring cursor
    DECLARE BGCursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT BGID, CreateDate FROM G2_BloodGlucose WHERE PatientID = @PatientID ORDER BY CreateDate ASC

    -- Opening cursor and starting the loop
    OPEN BGCursor
    FETCH NEXT BGCursor INTO @BGID, @CreateDate
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        -- Updating row with generated DateTime
        UPDATE G2_BloodGlucose SET CreateDate = @IncrementalDateTime WHERE BGID = @BGID

        -- Incrementing DateTime
        SET @IncrementalDateTime = DATEADD(hour, 1, @IncrementalDateTime)

        FETCH NEXT BGCursor INTO @BGID, @CreateDate
    END

    CLOSE BGCursor
    DEALLOCATE BGCursor

END
GO
```

I built it, to update a DateTime field in a table. So I increment a variable by 1 hour for every row the query finds.

The problem I'm actually having is these errors:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure UpdatePatientCreateDateWithDemoData, Line 27
Incorrect syntax near 'NEXT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure UpdatePatientCreateDateWithDemoData, Line 33
Incorrect syntax near 'NEXT'.
```

I rarely build stored procedure so I'm a bit lost. Would it be possible to have any tips about how to resolve these errors? I looked on several websites to compare my code, but can't find anything useful.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Avoid cursors if possible. Use set based operations instead. SQL is not a procedural language - don't use looping constructs in it if you an avoid it.

Comment: For this specific error, the problem is with the `FETCH NEXT`, it should be `FETCH NEXT FROM BGCursor INTO @BGID, @CreateDate`. You are missing the `FROM`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although cursors are probably a tool of the devil, if you want to use them, you need:

```
 FETCH NEXT FROM BGCursor INTO @BGID, @CreateDate
```

instead of

```
 FETCH NEXT BGCursor INTO @BGID, @CreateDate
```

See the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180152.aspx) for syntax.

Comment: All of my what! I can't believe it was only that. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

I think your syntax is incorrect you are missing the FROM Key word

```
FETCH NEXT FROM BGCursor INTO @BGID, @CreateDate
```